# Passing two parameters not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I extend my routes like this:

```
photos_patient_path(@patient, {:photoid => f.id })
```

creates:

```
http://localhost:3000/patients/79799/photos?photoid=6
```

In my rails controller i have:

```
def photos 
    @photos = @patient.photos.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8) 
    @photo = @photos.find(params[:photoid]) rescue nil
    @termins = @patient.termins.where("date >= ?", Date.today)
    render :show
  end
```

And in the view:

```
<% if @photo == nil %>
 <%= render 'patient_photos' %>
 <% else %>
 <%= render 'patient_photo' %>   
 <% end %>
```

**The code from above works, and now i tried to add another param:**

```
photos_patient_path(@patient, { :page => params[:page], :photoid => f.id })
```

creates:

```
http://localhost:3000/patients/79799/photos?page=2&photoid=15
```

But now when in my view i call:

```
<%= params[:photoid] %>
```

It returns nothing or better said nil! Why? Thanks

Comment: What values do you see in `params[]`?

Comment: {"page"=>"2", "photoid"=>"15", "action"=>"photos", "controller"=>"patients", "id"=>"79799"}

Comment: In my first link :photoid was first in the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an specific route for individual photos different from the "photos" path, I mean, some route like:

```
get 'patients/:patient_id/photos/:photo_id', to: 'patients#patient_photo', as: 'patient_photo'
```

now you don't need the if in your view

and in your controller you will have

```
def photos 
  @photos = @patient.photos.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8) 
  @termins = @patient.termins.where("date >= ?", Date.today)
end

def patient_photo
  @photo = @patient.photos.find(params[:photo_id])
end
```

I guess that will fix your issue and your urls will look better

EDIT: added a named route

and you create the path with patient_photo_path(@patient, photo_id)

EDIT 2: you may want to implement so fallback behavior on a before_filter if @patient.photos.find(params[:photo_id]) is nil to render the index or something like that